# How does one delete the error messages from XCode's Devices & Simulators window?

Tags: xcode

I have a long list of error in my devices window.
How do I get rid of them?

The errors persist even after removing derived data, restarting xcode, restarting the mac, or a combination of these....

[image]

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: No unfortunately not...

Answer (score 0):

These errors don't persist beyond the session. Quit Xcode and relaunch, or unpair and reconnect the device.

If you resolve the error (e.g. unlock the device), the error should disappear, but if the error has appeared multiple times, it may only clear the last error. It's safe to ignore the older errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, the errors persist. Even after removing derived data, restarting xcode, restarting the mac, and even with the combination of all above...